# How to clear floats properly

Tags: css

Css noob here in need of some advice.

I have a form that sometimes has 2 divs side-by-side (with input/labels inside/validators). Any further divs after this don't format correctly, not even with a clearfix.

```
[div] [div]
--> clear div goes here
[   div   ]
```

I've fixed it with another Div with css {clear:both;} but this is superfluous. Whats more I've found that IE needs a height on the clear div to honour any margin on the lower div.

Is there a better method of dealing with this?

Comment: You'll need to show us some code, preferably in jsfiddle

Comment: Floats? It's [all about the inline block](http://jsfiddle.net/S5afv/). (in my humble opinion) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's tough to see exactly what issue you're having without seeing the code, but hopefully this helps.

```
<div class="one" style="float: left;"> This div is floated left </div>

<div class="example1" style="clear: left;">this is text in example 1</div> <!-- notice clear left means this dive will appear after the float, no matter how much stuff is in the float -->
```

if class one is floated left, then example 1 would appear right next to it, but in this case you cleared the float to the left (which is class one) so example 1 appears below your floated object.